# Communicate Node.js with Python and fetch data delay

Tags: python, node.js, web-crawler

I'm trying to program `web crawler`.

I have `server.js / crawling.js / dataCrawler.py`

When I call `crawlData` that is defined in `crawling.js` at `server.js`, the method I defined in `crawling.js` using spawn for executing the `dataCrawler.py` gets called.

I need data in `server.js`, but executing `dataCrawler.py` takes a while So I cannot get proper data but null or undefined.

Do you have any solution ? or Anyone who has same issue?

My codes are below. (I don't put these perfectly. Just reference for structure)

---

//server.js

```
var crawler = require("./crawling")
var resultArr = crawler.crawlData();
console.log('nodeserver:', resultArr)
```

---

//crawling.js

```
exports.crawlData = ()=>{

    var dataArr = [];
    var temp;

    var py = spawn('python', ['dataCrawler.py']);
    var data = [totalUrl, gubun];
    var dataFromPy = null;


    py.stdout.on('data', function(result){
        var dataArr = encoding.convert(result, 'utf-8')
        dataArr = JSON.parse(encoding.convert(result, 'utf-8'));

        py.stdout.on('end', function(){
            temp = dataArr
        });

    });

    py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(data));

    py.stdin.end();

    return temp;

}
```

---

//dataCrawler.py

```
def crawling(url, gubun, page_count):

    idx = 0
    result = []
    jsonData = {}
    for i in range(1, page_count + 1):
        ....
        crawling code
        ....    
    return result


    def main():

    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    paraFromServer = json.loads(lines[0])
    url = paraFromServer[0]
    gubun = paraFromServer[1]

    result = crawling(url, gubun, page_count)

    print(result)


    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't account for the asynchronous nature of javascript. What you have to do is, pass in a callback method to `crawlData` method, which will be invoked once scraping is done.

```
exports.crawlData = (cb)=>{
 ....
 py.stdout.on('data', function(result){
    var dataArr = encoding.convert(result, 'utf-8')
    dataArr = JSON.parse(encoding.convert(result, 'utf-8'));

    py.stdout.on('end', function(){
        cb(dataArr); // ideally the pattern is cb(error, data)
    });

 });

...
```

So `server.js` becomes:

```
var crawler = require("./crawling")
crawler.crawlData((data) => { 
    console.log(data); 
    // Do whatever you want to do with the data.
});
```

Callbacks can cause [Callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). Try exploring `promises` or `async` / `await`.

Comment: Thx for answer. How can I use actual crawled data in server.js?

Comment: @Randy you have the data in callback method you passed. Made an edit to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [spawnSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) if running in parallel isn't a concern

```
exports.crawlData = () => {
    const result = spawnSync('python', ['dataCrawler.py'], {
      input: JSON.stringify([totalUrl, gubun])
    });

    return JSON.parse(encoding.convert(result, 'utf-8'));
}
```